# Azure Active Directory B2C: how to refresh a token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Currently I try to implement user authorization into an iOS app. Therefore we use Active Directory B2C.

Everything works fine, except the refreshing of my expired tokens. I call the request url (`fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_sign_in`) to get an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`. The response seems to be valid and the `access_token` works very well as long as it's not expired.

But if I want to get a new token (like it is described here: [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code/); see chapter 4) the request just gets responded with a **400: Bad Request**.

I can't find out, what I am doing wrong. Do you guys now a way, how to debug these requests or have some kind of checklist what needs to get configured within the Azure portal?

Thanks!

Edit: this is the request I am using:

```
POST /xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_local-account-signupin HTTP/1.1
HOST: login.microsoftonline.com
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
content-length: 1148

client_id=xxx&refresh_token=xxx&grant_type=refresh_token&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you're using to request the refreshed token?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my question.

Comment: And you are sure that your `HOST` is like what you posted here? Because in the referenced documentation it stays as `HOST: https://login.microsoftonline.com`, which indeed causes 400 Server Error with no further messages. I tried with couple of different AAD B2C Tenants, including one very old (created very early in the preview), and it all works as expected. Please make sure that your HOST parameter is indeed without `https` and your content-length matches the length of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for trying to solve my problem! It came out, that the `refresh_token` I was using was invalid. So if you are sure, that the request is correct, and you get just a **Bad Request** response, check the parameters one more time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify a value for the `scope` parameter.  The `scope` parameter is used to inform B2C which resource you are requesting a token for.  At this time you'll most likely want to use `scope=<client_id>` or `scope=openid`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I already tried to set several parameters for `scope`. Unfortunately I still get the 400 error. People on this page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code/ seem to have similar issues as mentioned in the comment area.